# Solving an equation of a sum of terms with the same exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation that simplifies to the equation below, that I need to solve for t.

$$
ab^t + cd^t = f
$$

All letters represent simple variables.

I don't remember/know enough of the exponentiation rules to figure this out. Neither wolfram alpha (free version) or symbolab.com can figure it out.

Someone asked for the original equation:

$$
\frac{(1+r_1)^t}{r_1}P_1+{P_v}_1(1+r_1)^t=\frac{P_2}{r_2}-(1+r_2)^t(\frac{P_2}{r_2}-{P_v}_2)+o
$$
For my uses:

${P_v}_1, {P_v}_2 > 10,000$

$P_1, P_2 > 100$

$0 < r_1,r_2 < 0.1$

Comment: You will need numerical methods. If Wolfram Alpha fails , probably even Lambert-W won't help.

Comment: Are $(a,b,c,e)$ all positive and greater than $1$?

Comment: Maybe if you share the original equation we can see other possibilities

Comment: $b^t$ and $d^t$ are not generally algebraically dependent (eg, take $(b,d)=(2,3)$). Hence, their sum generally lacks an elementary inverse.

Comment: The original equation added by popular demand.

Comment: As $r<<1$ we can approximate $(1+r)^t \approx 1+ r t+\frac 12r^2(t-1)t$ and then solve a second order polynomial to have a reasonable guess, and then proceed to refine the results.